# Line chart in ggplot using longitudinal panel data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have longitudinal panel dataset with information about where someone lived during a certain year, his occupation, and a dummy variable indicating whether the person moved or not.

Now I'm trying to create a line chart in ggplot to visualise how these moves fluctuate over time. I want to calculate the proportion that moved each year. However, I'm not sure on how to group all individuals by year and also include the dummy indicating whether someone moved or not. Additionally, I would like to see how these the moving fluctuations differed between different occupations.

The dataset looks something like this:

```
df <- tibble(id = rep(1:5, each = 5),
             year = rep(2010:2014, 5),
             moved = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1),
             occupation = c('carpenter','carpenter', 'carpenter', 'carpenter', 'carpenter', 'cleaner',
                            'cleaner', 'cleaner', 'cleaner', 'cleaner', 'mechanic', 'mechanic',
                            'mechanic', 'mechanic', 'mechanic', 'carpenter', 'carpenter', 'carpenter',
                            'carpenter', 'carpenter', 'cleaner', 'mechanic', 'carpenter', 'cleaner',
                            'cleaner'))
```

Would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this? So you group the occupation by specifying it as colour, then at every point, you use stat_summary to calculate the proportion (mean), and connect them using a line:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=year,y=moved,col=occupation)) + 
stat_summary(fun=mean,geom="point") + 
stat_summary(fun=mean,geom="line",alpha=0.7,linetype="dashed")
```

[image]